# Why does modal freezes on click of register button

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have a registration form inside a modal. By default, it is hidden. On click of a button, the form shows. The issue now is, after filling the form and submit button is clicked its supposed to send a request via ajax to the server but it kind of freezes the page. If I open another tab and come back to it then it reloads the page.

I tried couple of test to see if the register button triggers the request by alerting a string say alert("hello"). It gets alerted after then it freezes.

This is the js code

```
//register
$("#reg-form").on("click", "#register", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(" clicked");
    let email = $("#email").val();

    let fname = $("#fname").val();
    let oname = $("#oname").val();
    let phone = $("#phone").val();
    let country = $("#country").val();
    alert(phone);
    $.ajax({
        url: "../../../../store/register",
        type: "post",

        data: {
            fname: fname,
            oname: oname,
            phone: phone,
            password: password,
            email: email,
            //register:'register'
        },
        //  dataType:'json',
        success: function (dt) {
            alert(dt);
        },
        
    }); //ajax
}); //register
```

The HTML form inside the modal is this..

```
  <!-- modal for registration-->
  <div style="display:none;" id="reg-modal" class="modal is-active">
    
    
  <div class="modal-background"></div>
  
  <div class="modal-card">
    <header class="modal-card-head">
      <p  class="button modal-card-title baseColor white ">Register </p>
      <button id="reg-close" class="button is-danger delete" aria-label="close"></button>
    </header>
    <section class="modal-card-body">
      
        
      <!-- Content ... -->
     
 
     <div class="notification is-light is-link">You are not currently logged in. Register quickly and access our features<hr><b>Ensure</b> you provide a working <b>phone number</b> and <b>email</b>
  </div>  
  
  
<div style="display:flex; flex-flow:row wrap;" class="columns is-mobilee box">
    
    <form id="reg-form" action="../../../store/register" method="post">
<div  class="column is-half-mobile is-three-quarters-desktop is-half-tablett">
   <div class="control has-icons-right">  
 <input id="email" class="input is-link " name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email..." required><span class="icon is-right baseColor white"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
     </div>
     </div>
     
   <!--hhh-->  
     
   <div class="column is-half-mobile is-half-three-quarters-desktopp is-half-tablett">
   <div class="control has-icons-right">  
 <input id="phone" class="input is-link " name="phone" type="tel" placeholder="Phone No.." required><span class="icon is-right baseColor white"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></span>
     </div>
     </div>
       
        <!--hhh-->  
     
   <div class="column is-half-mobile is-half-desktopp is-half-tablett">
   <div class="control has-icons-right">  
 <input id="fname" class="input is-link " name="fname" type="text" placeholder="Surname" required><span class="icon is-right baseColor white"><i class="fa fa-user-o"></i></span>
     </div>
     </div>
      
      
     <div class="column is-half-mobile is-three-quarters-desktopp is-half-tablett  has-icons-right">  
     <div class="control has-icons-right">
<input id="oname" class="input is-link " name="oname" type="text" placeholder="Other Names" required><span class="icon is-right baseColor white"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
     </div>
     </div>   
     
     
         <div class="column is-half-mobile is-three-quarters-desktopp is-half-tablett  has-icons-right">  
     <div class="control has-icons-right">
<input id="password" class="input is-link " name="password" type="text" placeholder="Password" required><span class="icon is-right baseColor white"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></span>
     </div>
     </div>    
     
     
     
   <div class="select is-link"> 
 <select id="country" name="country">
    <option>COUNTRY</option>
    
    <option value="AU">Australia</option>
    
    <option value="BR">Brazil</option>
    <option value="CM">Cameroon</option>
    <option value="CI">Cote D'Ivoire</option>
    <option value="EG">Egypt</option>
    <option value="FR">France</option>
    <option value="DE">Germany</option>
    <option value="GH">Ghana</option>
    <option value="IN">India</option>
    <option value="IT">Italy</option>
    <option value="KE">Kenya</option>
    <option value="MX">Mexico</option>
    <option value="NG">Nigeria</option>
    <option value="PT">Portugal</option>
    <option value="ES">Spain</option>
    <option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="US">United States</option>
</select>      
     </div>
     
 </div>   <!--columns-->
 
 
       <input type="submit" name="register" id="register" class="button is-link is-rounded block mb-1" value="Register"> <span class="ml-2 fa fa-arrow-right"></span> 
    <!--  </button>  --> 
     
</div>

</div> < /form> < !--end of modal
  for registration -->
```

And finally the server side

```
function register() {
    //clean the data     
    function clean($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        $data = htmlentities($data);
        return $data;
    }
    //if(isset($_POST['register'])){
    $email = clean($_POST['email']);
    $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    if ($email == false) {
        echo "Please enter a valid email";
        exit;
    }
    $password = clean($_POST['password']);
    $password = filter_var($password, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $fname = clean($_POST['fname']);
    $fname = filter_var($fname, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $oname = clean($_POST['oname']);
    $oname = filter_var($oname, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $phone = clean($_POST['phone']);
    $phone = filter_var($phone, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $country = clean($_POST['country']);
    $country = filter_var($country, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $datas = array($fname, $oname, $password, $country, $phone, $email);
    foreach($datas as $d) {
        if (strlen($d) < 1) {
            echo "You must not leave any field empty!!!";
            exit;
        } else {
            $test = "passed";
        }
    } //foreach
    if ($test == "passed") {
        //insert to db
        echo "1";
    }
    //  } //if    
} //func reg
```

Sorry I don't wish to type all this code to bother you but to make the question clear. If I remove the js and process the form , it works.

The button that displays the registration modal also work well.

I tried to select with

```
$(document).on('click','#register',function (){
......
```

Still the same result. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "freezes" exactly? You mean the whole browser becomes unreponsive? Or it just doesn't do the next thing you expected it to? What debugging have you done? Have you opened the browser's Developer Tools and checked the Console and Network tool for errors and other clues? Have you tried to use the JS debugger to trace what the code does?

Comment: The modal behaves as if it hooks and after a while the page will reload. Of you try to fill any field on the form  it won't respond

Comment: `behaves as if it hooks`...no idea what that means, sorry. Be more specific and clear.

Comment: It looks like you just don't do anything with the result of the modal's register click - maybe close the modal in the `success:` callback?  (where you have `alert(dt)`)

Comment: What does F12 Network tab show for your AJAX call?

Comment: Also, drop a break point on your server side `register()` function.  Does the AJAX call hit the function?  Does it return the result you expect?

Comment: There's nothing shown here which would cause the page to reaload - unless there's a JS error early on which causes none of the event handling code to work at all, in which case the form would just post back as normal rather than the postback being intercepted and handled via JS/AJAX. Again, please check for errors in your browser's Developer Tools.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your example code does not appear to be correct. There are orphaned HTML Tags. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks to you all. I was able to figure out the issue by commenting out the data part of the ajax. So I realized I didn't declare password  variable and it was sent to the back end. Thanks once again